# Answer the Unanswered Event

Tags: discussion

Since the last time someone asked about improving the [unanswered questions](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190/how-to-improve-the-number-of-answered-questions) metric, we've had another drop off.

I thought now might be a good time to setup a chat event to improve this.
Would anyone be interested in an "answer the unanswered" event, where we all hop over to chat and work together to answer as many of the unanswered questions as possible (we don't necessarily have to use Tor.SE chat either if people would rather use IRC)? Do you think we could get enough knowledgeable people on at the same time to make it worthwhile?

Either way, please consider checking out the 300 or so [unanswered questions](https://tor.stackexchange.com/unanswered) and answering one or two if you can.

Comment: I'd suggest using `#tor` in OFTC. Even if there are too few people at SE, `#tor` is quite crowded and maybe someone decides to answer the question. So we can attract more users. :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would be definitely interested and I guess if we announce it in several Tor channels we can attract some knowledgable people. As I said in comments I'd suggest to discuss our issues in `#tor` or `#tor-dev`. In both channels are a lot of users which know about or even develop Tor.

Comment: tor.SE needs indeed someething to attract people. It is like that the majority of tor users don't even know about its existence.

Comment: A good way to attract people is to have some lines in [Tor Weekly News](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/TorWeeklyNews). So if you want to help there, please edit the next/current issue.